# Schema-less in All layers

Tags: java, jsonschema, schemaless

I have use case where schema of my entities keep on changing again and again. 
Based on that i have to change/add new business rules which is not scalable for me.

I am trying to go schema-less by using JSON documents in **my data , service and ui layer**.

I want to avoid creating DAO(Data Access objects), Data Transfer object(for sending objects) , View Model objects that are major problem for me in changing schema and deploy again.

Are there any good frameworks from where i can take help in this ..

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the Java API for JSON Processing?
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/json-1973242.html

https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=353